# iptables - Two entries for one rule | iptables -A INPUT -s localhost -j ACCEPT

Tags: iptables, netfilter

I am issuing the following rule from the shell prompt:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s localhost -j ACCEPT
```

After that, when I check iptables -L, I see two entries for the same.

The summary of iptables-save -c before and after:

```
root@debian:~# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov  3 09:11:15 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [8:528]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:492]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov  3 09:11:15 2017
root@debian:~# iptables -A INPUT -s localhost -j ACCEPT
root@debian:~# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov  3 09:11:24 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [6:396]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:496]
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov  3 09:11:24 2017
root@debian:~#
```

Any idea, why there are two entries for one rule?